# I can´t load gpx files with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, gpx

I have a problem with a code when I try to load gpx files with ajax. I get next error:

GET http://localhost:49741/entrenamiento_matutino.gpx 404 (Not Found) jquery-2.1.3.js:8625

The code of the line 8625 is: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

If I convert gpx file in a xml file, works correctly, but i need work with gpx files.

This ajax code:

read: function () {

```
    var that = this;
    if (this.track) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //url:'entrenamiento_matutino.xml',
            url:'entrenamiento_matutino.gpx',
            context: that,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: this.leergpx,
            error: function (ex) {
                alert(ex.status + ": " + ex.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it has to be a server side issue. Maybe the server software you use needs to be explicitly configured to serve .gpx files. What if you just enter http://localhost:49741/entrenamiento_matutino.gpx into the address bar of your browser? Do you get a 404 Not Found response then too?

Answer (score 0):

I Forget to put the solution here. It was a problem of MIME, I hadn't  settings to gpx. Thanks for help.